# How do I use jQuery.Get() to return web contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, get

I'm trying to use the jQuery.Get() function to return the contents of a webpage.

Something along the lines of -

```
  var data =  $.get("http://mysite...../x.php");
```

I know the above is wrong, can someone help my out here?

Comment: Did you read this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery ajax calls are asynchronous, so you'll need to do something on the callback of the get.

> ```
>  $.get('http://mysite...../x.php', function(data) {
>   $('.result').html(data);
>   alert('Load was performed.');
> });
> ```

Also, bear in mind that $.get is just a convenience handler.  Even the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) indicates that it calls $.ajax.  With that in mind, it's always a better idea to call the method directly, as it's a couple less calls pushed on to the stack and you save a few CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this:

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

$.get does not return the result of the query.  It is an AJAX call and the first A in AJAX stands for "asynchronous".  That means that the function returns before the AJAX request is complete.  You therefore need to supply a function as the second argument of the call:

```
var data =  $.get("http://mysite...../x.php", function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ for more examples and options that you can set.